# Split string with multiple words using regex in python

Tags: python

Suppose I have a  expression

```
exp="\"OLS\".\"ORDER_ITEMS\".\"QUANTITY\"  <50 and  \"OLS\".\"PRODUCTS\".\"PRODUCT_NAME\"  = 'Kingston' or \"OLS\".\"ORDER_ITEMS\".\"QUANTITY\"  <20"
```

I want to split the expression by **and** , **or** so that my result will be

```
exp=['\"OLS\".\"ORDER_ITEMS\".\"QUANTITY\"  <50','\"OLS\".\"PRODUCTS\".\"PRODUCT_NAME\"  = 'Kingston'','\"OLS\".\"ORDER_ITEMS\".\"QUANTITY\"  <20']
```

This is what i have tried:

```
import re
res=re.split('and|or|',exp)
```

but it will split by each character how can we make it split by word?

Comment: Yes and what is your issue exactly? Have you googled 'split string python'?

Comment: yes shown what i have tried

Comment: @Julien with split string we cannot pass multiple delimiters right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import itertools
exp=itertools.chain(*[y.split('or') for y in exp.split('and')])
exp=[x.strip() for x in list(exp)]
```

Explanation: 1st split on 'and'. Now try  spitting each element obtained on 'or'. This will create list of lists. Using itertools, create a flat list & strip extra spaces from each new element in the flat list

Answer (score 1):

Your regex has three alternatives: "and", "or" or the empty string: `and|or|`

Omit the trailing `|` to split just by those two words.

```
import re
res=re.split('and|or', exp)
```

Note that this will not work reliably; it'll split on any instance of "and", even when it's in quotes or part of a word. You could make it split only on full words using `\b`, but that will still split on a product name like `'Black and Decker'`. If you need it to be reliable and general, you'll have to parse the string using the full syntax (probably using an off-the-shelf parser, if it's standard SQL or similar).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 2 steps: `[ss for s in exp.split(" and ") for ss in s.split(' or ')]`

Comment: but it wont be dynamic I guess if I have a expression with only **and** `exp="\"OLS\".\"ORDER_ITEMS\".\"QUANTITY\"  <50 and  \"OLS\".\"PRODUCTS\".\"PRODUCT_NAME\"  = 'Kingston'` ?